# Excel VBA: Read decimals as "," and convert it to "." while calculating

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm conducting an optimization using *Solver* and I've had some issues now with decimals. Using a Swedish Excel my default decimal point is a comma "," but I've read from forums that *Solver* need to have decimals in the form of a period sign "."

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Worksheets("Blad1").Activate
  SolverReset

  SolverOk SetCell:=B63, MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range("B45:B62")

  SolverAdd CellRef:=B45, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=P24        
  SolverAdd CellRef:=B45, Relation:=3, FormulaText:=O24
  SolverAdd CellRef:=L45, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=L3
  SolverAdd CellRef:=L46, Relation:=3, FormulaText:=L4
  SolverAdd CellRef:=B63, Relation:=3, FormulaText:=B42      
  SolverSolve
End Sub
```

The above is my code with in short (there are many more constraints in reality). Here all cell references are to cells containing decimal number with delimiter ",". I tried to add a Custom Format of the type "0.00" (if it's not possible to convert the decimals to periods and convert it back to commas in the answer, then that's not the optimal solution but an OK solution) but it resulted in integers, say 3, becoming "0.03" where the intention were to have it like "3.00".

Is there a way to read a decimal number having "," convert it to "." while doing calculation and subsequentially provide the answer with "," without having to "globally" change the decimals from commas to periods, as I have many Excel workbooks which will not work as intended using ".".

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Tested some more now and I realize that the Solver actually *can* "handle" comma decimals. Indeed Solver can print a solution consisting of comma decimals, however it appears that some functions, for instance SolverSolve, is based around end point decimals. I tested to implement the following in a new Workbook:

```
Sub Makro1()
   Dim MyNumber1 As Double
   Dim MyNumber2 As Double

   Set MyNumber1 = Sheets("Blad1").Cell(20, 1).Value
   Set MyNumber2 = Sheets("Blad1").Cell(21, 1).Value
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim rSetCell As Range, rByChange As Range, rPrecision As Range
   Range("A1").Resize(1, 4) = Array("Precision", "c", "b", "a")
   For i = 1 To 16
       Set rPrecision = Range("A1").Offset(i, 0)
       Set rSetCell = Range("A1").Offset(i, 1)
       Set rByChange = Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Resize(1, 2)
       rSetCell.Formula = "=SQRT(" & rByChange(1).Address & "^2+" & rByChange(2).Address & "^2)"
       rPrecision = 10 ^ -i
       SolverReset
       SolverOk MyNumber1, 3, 5, rByChange.Address
       SolverOptions Precision:=rPrecision.Value
       SolverAdd rByChange(1).Address, 4
       SolverAdd MyNumber1, 1, MyNumber2
       SolverSolve True
   Next
 End Sub
```

(Where the vast majority of code is taken from Andreas Killer at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/excel-solver-macros-do-not-work-when-using-comma/8b595198-8492-4382-89c4-5fc144f7bc43?page=1 in order to check whether the program can print comma decimals, which it could).

Adding `SolverAdd MyNumber1, 1, MyNumber2` where MyNumber1 is cell A20, which is 2,3 and MyNumber2 is A21 which is 2,5. Hence, the solution would not be feasible if the program actually could manage comma decimals (these parameters are never changed, and the constraint is always violated). Checking the TypeName Before adding the Dim Double for the two variables showed that A20 where, in fact, recognized as an String.

Trying to implement this solution gives me the error `Object Required` and a highlight on the code snippet `Sub Makro1()`. Why won't this work? Has anyone a clue how to make this work without needing to change the system language for all Excel workbooks, so I can avoid to adjust every Excel sheet I've ever created containing formulae?

EDIT: 
`Set MyNumber1 = Sheets("Blad1").Cell(20, 1).Value` and `Set MyNumber2 = ..` both gives the error `Object Required`.

Comment: You can temporary change the decimal separator. Please, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207.aspx Note: you have to change it before you load file with data.

Comment: @MaciejLos Thanks for your answer! I've tried that solution, and the Solver actually finds a solution. However, the solution does not comply to all restrictions which I take as the compiler Thinks that some values are strings instead of numbers.

Comment: You're very welcome. Cheers, Maciej.

Comment: If you step thorough the code which line does it fail on?  You need to add error handling, which I have added to you question code for you.

Comment: @HarveyFrench Thanks for your time invested into this. I actually didn't know there was such a nifty Error handling in VBA, will definitely use that henceforth. Running that program, `Set MyNumber1 = Sheets("Blad1").Cell(20,1).Value` gave me the error `Object Required`. Commenting out this line, the same happened for `Set MyNumber2` which is defined similarily. Commenting out this line as well gave me no errors, so I fathom those two lines causes the errors.

Comment: An object required error on those lines to me most likely indicates your worksheet reference is failing to find a sheet of that name.  Try this:  `Dim Blad1 as Worksheet: Set Blad1 = Sheets("Blad1")` `Debug.Print Blad1 is Nothing`.  If you run that, what do you get - True or False?

Comment: ie do you have a sheet that has a name "Blad1" .  In the immediate window (DEV window>Ribbon>VIEW>Immediate). type this    "? worksheets("Blad1").name "   if ti gives you an error you do not have a sheet with that name IN THE workbook that has the code you are running!

Comment: Also see here for a good into to error handling: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that solver accepts the cell reference not the cell values.

The MSDN page doesn't give any switches or options to change the format of numbers.

I am surprised that a comma is used in Sweeden for the decimal point.

What happens if you change your international settings in the  control panel>Language settings (in additional settings you have to type a , no select on the combo).  You can change the number format used.

I change my decimal point to use a comma and this chnaged how excel stored and showed it it.  (the range properties .value .value2 and .text all had a comma instead of a full stop)

Try changing the language or the number format and see if this changes how they are displayed in excel so you can use solver.

Another concern is that they may not be stored as numbers in excel, but as text.

Please experiment.

Also here's some code that probably won't help, but may be of use:

This VBA function
    replace("Mystringwith,commas", ",", ".") 
will output
    "Mystringwith.commas"

Although the parameters are a string you can use it with numbers as it will work (it implicitly converts the numbers to strings).

Also, the following code might give you some inspiration.

```
Sub aaa()
    Dim c As Range

    Set c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B14")

    c.Value = 1198.3
    c.NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"

    Debug.Print c.Value      ' 1198.3
    Debug.Print c.Value2     ' 1198.3
    Debug.Print c.Text       ' £1,198.3

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. As a fun fact, there are actually more countries which uses "," as a decimal point than a full stop. 

My concern is also that the program handles the values as string, which I believe is also evident from my solution using Maciej Los solution. 

The problem is that if I alter the language for the system as a whole, that will alter the decimals in all other reports I have, which causes problem as Excel Formulaes in Sweden uses "," decimals, and flags for error if "." are used. Will Think more about the code snippet in order to try to implement it.

Comment: @Gustav  what character do you use for this:   £1,000   ?   Why not use a "." always!

Comment: No need for a comma for thousands, so it would simply be £ 1000 or £ 1 000 :)